# validation with variable variables not working

Tags: php, variables, validation

```
$method = 'post';

$method = strtoupper($method);
echo $method.'test1';

$method = '_'.$method;
echo $method.'test2';

$method = $$method;
echo $method.'test3';
```

Why doesn't this print the content of $_POST between 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `$method['test3']` to access the elements of the `$_POST` array. The dot `.` operator does string concatenation. Square brackets `[]` are used for array access.

Comment: No, I want $_SESSION, $_COOKIE, $_POST and $_GET from 'session', 'cookie', 'post' and 'get'.

Comment: I think I'm going to end up using

if($method == 'post') $method = $_POST;
if($method == 'get') $method = $_GET;
if($method == 'session') $method = $_SESSION;
if($method == 'cookie') $method = $_COOKIE;

Answer (score 1):

In addition to John Kugelman's excellent point, I would use the following

```
$method = $_POST;

echo $method['test1'];

echo $method['test2'];

echo $method['test3'];
```

and not bother with trying to access a *contant* array name via a string

If you really insist on using a string to access these, you could

```
$method = "post";
$method = strtoupper($method."_");    
if (isset(${$method})) {
  $method = ${$method};

  echo $method['test1'];

  echo $method['test2'];

  echo $method['test3'];
}
```